# Asp.Net Core MVC on Azure Cloud Services?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

There are a lot of articles on Asp.Net Core 1.0 and its cross-platform features. I know that it's possible to deploy it to Linux, OSX, Windows. I've read a lot fo step-by-step articles how to do that. But I still have no ideas how to publish it as Cloud Service Web Role in Azure project.

I have a huge distributed system including Web roles, Worker roles and Cache Worker role. Thinking of Asp.Net Core 1.0 and this I faced with next problems:

1. Is it possible to deploy Asp.Net MVC Core site as Web role of Azure project? Or I should host it on Worker Role?
2. Is there ready-to-use Azure Emulator for Linux? In other words, how to debug my distributed system with this "cross-platform" if I decide migrate and host my system on Linux?

Comment: Have you read this post https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs.html and https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/examples/azure/aspnet-core10-azure-web-apps ?

Comment: @douglas-thomas, yes. Both about publishing o Azure as site or web application. But i'm talking about cloud service (web role)

Comment: Would also like to deploy Asp.Net core to Web roles..

Comment: now it is .Net Core 2.0 and no Web roles support yet ... Web App or Service Fabric

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible but with some tricks:
https://oren.codes/2017/10/16/using-asp-net-core-with-azure-cloud-services/

PS. You can vote for this feature here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/35096002-support-hosting-asp-net-core-in-cloud-services